# Rspec expect(method) vs expect(method).to be_true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've just started diving into TDD with RSpec and Rails and I've found that if I'm testing a method that should come out to be true that the test will work if i use expect(method) instead of expect(method).to be_true.

```
it "is true" do
  expect(subject).to be_true
  #Works the same as...
  expect(subject)
end
```

Is there any reason to not use the expect without .to, will it break the tests or not catch certain failures? Just wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not achieving what you think you are. `expect(false)` does not fail. `expect(true)` only succeeds because nothing is being tested.
For example if you had a spec with the following:

```
describe "something" do
  it "does something" do
    false
    puts expect(false)
    # anything that evaluates to false
  end
end
```

You would get something like this when you run rspec:

```
#<RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x007ff0b35a28b8\>
.

Finished in 0.00061 seconds
1 example, 0 failures
```

Essentially you are not asserting anything and `expect(subject)` evaluates to ExpectationTarget.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a coincidence that the latter works.

Every expect statement evaluates to true or false one way or the other.

For example

```
arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
expect(arr).to include('a')
```

will return true because `arr` includes `'a'`.

So in your case `expect(subject)` and `expect(subject).to be_true` is somewhat equivalent to the following:

```
bool = true
if bool
  # Do something here

if bool == true
  # Do something here
```

To make a long story short, it doesn't matter, but I would prefer `expect(subject).to be_true` for readability purposes.